# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '`' SQL Server management studio

Tags: sql

I am facing the problem while executing the query in SQL Server management studio.
Error is
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '`'.
For reference, screenshot is attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsOO9.jpg)

Assistance required in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is making reference to the ` character that you're surrounding your column names with. When creating a table the columns do not need to be surrounded by anything (unless it is a name containing a space which would need to be enclosed in square brackets).

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick response.  Actually i have to import the existing database. When I try to import DB, lots of these type of messages showing.  Thats why I tried to execute this small piece of query.

Comment: With refrence to attached image, what is the issue while defining field of category id having data type int(10). Its also highlighting as an error.

Comment: Defining an int at table creation doesn't take a length. If you need to restrict the length of the number in that column define it as decimal or numeric.